# CakePHP 3.0.0 cascade dependent deletes

Tags: cascade, cakephp-3.0

If I have the following in some model tables; As, Bs, Cs and Ds.

They have these associations defined:

**AsTable**:

```
$this->hasOne('Bs', [
  'dependent' => true,
  'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
]);
```

**BsTable:**

```
$this->belongsTo('As', [
  'foreignKey' => 'A_id',
]);
$this->hasMany('Cs', [
  'foreignKey' => 'B_id',
  'dependent' => true,
  'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
]);
```

**CsTable:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Bs', [
  'foreignKey' => 'B_id',
]);
$this->hasMany('Ds', [
  'foreignKey' => 'C_id',
  'dependent' => true,
  'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
]);
```

**DsTable:**

```
$this->belongsTo('Cs', [
  'foreignKey' => 'C_id',
]);
```

Deleting an A now deletes the A, the B and any linked Cs but the Ds remain.

Deleting a C causes linked Ds to be deleted.

Why doesn't deleting an A also delete Ds linked to the Cs which are deleted?

How can I make it so it does?

EDIT:
Cake exact version 3.0.0

Looking at the SQL in the debugkit sql log it seems that the sequence is wrong to me.

```
select from Bs where A_id = a_id (finds record with id "b_id")
delete from Cs where B_id = b_id 
select from Cs where B_id = b_id 
delete from Bs where id = b_id 
delete from A where id = a_id
```

(replaced table names and ids for readability)

Never touches D at all and obviously since it deletes from Cs before selecting it's never going to get the id(s) to be able to find anything in D.

Mightily confused!

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version too! The associations are looking good to me, using 3.0.2 it [**works just fine for me as is**](https://gist.github.com/ndm2/e936948d1c703773fee8). You'll have to do some debugging, start by checking the queries that are being issued (use **[DebugKit](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html)**).

Comment: Thanks for the comment ndm I've updated the question.

It's very confusing, I'm getting to the point where I might manually delete the records in C first, let them delete Ds then delete A so I can move on, but I don't like a solution which feels like it is superfluous. Can't really understand why...

Comment: Does the SQL log show any "Generated Models" (_The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete class..._)? Do you have any `beforeFind()` or `beforeDelete()` callbacks on your table classes? Are your tables using any behaviors? Could you please try it with the latest 3.0.2 release?

Comment: It _does_ but only in the initial select and for an unrelated model, let's call it X (C belongsToMany X but this is not one of the ones I'm concerned with).

Comment: Commenting out the association which causes the auto generated model message doesn't change the results regarding the problem above

Comment: You should not comment out, you need to fix the problem that DebugKit is telling you to solve :)

Comment: Ok but since it refers to a model *not* pertaining to _this_ problem I commented out so can work on this problem first... any suggestions?

Comment: Added the missing table - no difference

Comment: Did debugkit stop showing the error?

Comment: Yep but had no effect on the problem in the question

Comment: So what's with the other questions? Callbacks? Behaviors? Upgrade?

Comment: Oops!


Missed the other questions sorry, no beforeFind/Delete callbacks. Just upgraded and would you believe it, it's FIXED!


Not sure what has changed but thanks; should have tried upgrading earlier but am trying to finish an application and was going to upgrade at the end and then try to fix any breakages.


If you posted the need to upgrade as an answer I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading you CakePHP installation to the latest 3.0 stable release